# Progress bar, c#

Tags: c#, progress-bar

I am currently working on a app that has multi web browsers on a tab control with progress bars on them. To save me duplicating code i wanted to create a method where i pass the progress bar name into a function. I have created the following below but i am getting this error.

'string' does not contain a definition for 'Maximum' and no extension method 'Maximum' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
  private void PassPBName(string PBName)
        {

            // Event for the browser
            AxSHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_ProgressChangeEvent e;

            /* The CurrentProgress variable from the raised event
                  * gives you the current number of bytes already downloaded
                  * while the MaximumProgress is the total number of bytes
                  * to be downloaded */
            if (e.progress < e.progressMax)
            {
                // Check if the current progress in the progress bar
                // is >= to the maximum if yes reset it with the min
                if (PBName.Value >= PBName.Maximum)
                    PBName.Value = PBName.Minimum;
                else
                    // Just increase the progress bar
                    PBName.PerformStep(); 
            }
            else
                // When the document is fully downloaded
                // reset the progress bar to the min (0)
                PBName.Value = PBName.Minimum;
        }
        private void WBIntranet_ProgressChange(object sender, AxSHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_ProgressChangeEvent e)
        {

            string progressBar = PBIntranet.Value.ToString();
            PassPBName(progressBar);
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution if anyone else wants to know how to do this.

```
private void PassPBName(ToolStripProgressBar PBName, AxSHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_ProgressChangeEvent e)
    {
              /* The CurrentProgress variable from the raised event
              * gives you the current number of bytes already downloaded
              * while the MaximumProgress is the total number of bytes
              * to be downloaded */
        if (e.progress < e.progressMax)
        {
            // Check if the current progress in the progress bar
            // is >= to the maximum if yes reset it with the min
            if (PBName.Value >= PBName.Maximum)
                PBName.Value = PBName.Minimum;
            else
                // Just increase the progress bar
                PBName.PerformStep();
        }
        else
            // When the document is fully downloaded
            // reset the progress bar to the min (0)
            PBName.Value = PBName.Minimum;
    }

    private void WBIntranet_ProgressChange(object sender, AxSHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_ProgressChangeEvent e)
    {

        //Pass the PB bar name to PassPBName function to show current progress.
         PassPBName (PBIntranet, e);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you send the name of the progressbar, you need to use something like the FindControl method to find the control. It's better if you send a reference to the progressbar control instead:

```
private void PassPBReference(ProgressBar PBName) {
  ...
}
```

and call it using just:

```
PassPBReference(PBIntranet);
```

(You should of course make up a better name for the method, that reflects what it does and not just how you pass the parameters to it.)

Answer (score 1):

You have a string named `PBName`, but you are using it as if it were a progress bar class.  Perhaps you meant to pass the class in?  Assuming that `PBIntranet` is the actual progess bar class, it looks like you should be passing that into your `PassPBName` function.  Just guessing, you also need to pass in `e` from  your `WBIntranet_ProgressChange` event as well, not locally declare another in `PassPBName`, which I don't think will work as you intend.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference an object by just having it's name in a variable.  You would have to access it through Reflection.  Something like this:

```
Using System.Reflection;

ProgressBar myProgress = (ProgressBar)this.GetType().GetField(PBName).GetValue(this);
```

I am a little sketchy on the syntax, but maybe this will help push you further along.  Once you have the actual object, then you can access the Maxmimum/Minimum/etc.